# What are the benefits of using resourceful routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, resources

Is there a reason I should be using resourceful routes, even if I don't want a certain controller to have every single route created by `resources :controllers`?

For example, if I wanted every route but `get controllers/edit`, is there a reason I shouldn't remove the line `resources :controllers` and just manually add `get controllers/new`, `delete controllers/destroy`, etc, leaving out `edit`?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all resource routes except one as in your example, you could do:

```
resources :posts, except: :edit
```

This is definitely better than writing 7 lines to exclude one of the 8 routes provided by `resources`.

Excluding 2 actions:

```
resources :posts, except: [:edit, :update]
```

Including only 2 actions:

```
resources :posts, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created for more details.

Side note: Not a good idea to name a resource as `controllers`. It is allowed, but will cause a lot of confusion as `Controller` has special meaning in the rails world. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: So resources doesn't actually do anything other than consolidate those 8 lines of code into one line?